# Transform a string of an object to an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, ejs

I am trying to take an object from the server-side and bring it to an ejs file to use it in javascript.

The object inside the javascript looks like this:

```
   var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
   span.innerHTML = "<%= JSON.stringify(positions) %>";
   var positions = span.innerText;
   span.remove()
   console.log(positions)
```

and it returns a string like this one:

```
"
    {
        '0': { foo: foo },
        '1': { foo: boo },
        '2': { foo: doo }
    }
    "
```

Is there a way for me to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Why? I mean sure, you can parse the JSON, but the object is already available in the EJS as an object--why not render it as JS from the outset?

Comment: Useful question @DaveNewton.  I do see `innerHTML` being written and `innerText` being read, so this will strip markup. It's likely ziv's error to have assigned a JSON string to HTML in the first place.  I doubt it was intentional.  e.g.  `span.innerHTML=JSON.stringify({msg:"<b>hello</b>"})` `span.innerText` --> `{"msg":"hello"}`   **be careful!**

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign a variable to the stringified positions (no quotes) and it becomes a javascript object.  Then to display it stringify that object again.

(This "renders it as JS from the outset").

```
const myJSObj = <%= JSON.stringify(positions) %>;
console.log(JSON.stringify(myJSObj));
```